# How do I console.log the following objects in ES6?

Tags: javascript, console.log

how do I console log the result ["cat", "mouse"] using the ES6 method?

this is my current code and it's not working when I console.log(collectionAnimals)

```js
function collectAnimals(...animalList) {  
    return animalList;
}


collectAnimals("cat", "mouse"); 
console.log(collectAnimals)
```

Comment: `console.log(collectAnimals("cat", "mouse"))` or `const x = collectAnimals("cat", "mouse"); console.log(x);`

Comment: `console.log(collectAnimals)` -> `console.log(collectAnimals("cat", "mouse"))` or `const result = collectAnimals("cat", "mouse");  console.log(result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the values in a variable..

Here in this line:

```
collectAnimals("cat", "mouse");
```

you are not storing it anywhere therefore as soon as that line executes the data formed or created from it, is deleted

So, store it in a variable like this

```
let x = collectAnimals("cat", "mouse");
console.log(x);
```

and then print "x"